# import and work with dates in excel r

Tags: r, excel, date, import, dataframe

I imported a database from excel to r. I have a variable says "Date of birth" with excel format dd/mm/yyyy and I want to pass to format dd-mm-yyyy to can to work with class type Date.

```
> c
                      Athlete Gender Date.of.birth Age       Country
1         SABRINA MOCKENHAUPT  women    06/12/1980  33       Germany
2             IRINA MIKITENKO  women    23/08/1972  41       Germany
3         MARILSON DOS SANTOS    man    08/10/1977  36        Brazil
4                   RYAN HALL    man    14/10/1982  31 United States
5                 TIKI GELANA  women    22/10/1987  26      Ethiopia
```

I used this class change, `c$Date.of.birth<-as.Date(c$Date.of.birth)`but it doesn't change correctly dd / mm / yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy

Tank you for your help!

Comment: `format(as.Date(c$Date.of.birth),"%d-%m-%y")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To coerce your data to  `Date` type:

```
as.Date(dat$Date.of.birth,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Or better using `lubridate` package:

```
dmy(dat$Date.of.birth)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell as.Date how the original date is formatted, and then format the date again to dd-mm-yyyy.

```
format(as.Date("06/12/1980", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```